# [Highcharts][jQuery] How to get DateTime from XML to jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, xml, list, highcharts

I need to plot some datetime intervals to a Highchart chart. I have an XML file structured like this:

```
<chart>
    <categories>
        <item>Status</item>
    </categories>
    <series>
        <name>Breakdown</name>
        <data>
      <axis>0</axis>
            <low>2013,07,03, 0, 0, 0</low>
      <high>2013, 07, 03, 4, 0, 0</high>
        </data>
    </series>
    <series>
        <name>Production</name>
        <data>
      <axis>0</axis>
            <low>2013, 07, 03, 10, 0, 0</low>
      <high>2013, 07, 03, 12, 0, 0</high>
        </data>
    </series>
    <series>
        <name>TrialRun</name>
        <data>
      <axis>0</axis>
            <low>2013, 07, 03, 14, 0, 0</low>
      <high>2013, 07, 03, 15, 0, 0</high>
        </data>
    </series>
    <series>
        <name>ChangeOver</name>
        <data>
      <axis>0</axis>
            <low>2013, 07, 03, 4, 0, 0</low>
      <high>2013, 07, 03, 10, 0, 0</high>
        </data>
    </series>
</chart>
```

How can I extract the date from the code and parse it to jQuery in UTC format

I have tryed with the code bellow but it doesn't plot any values (date) to my chart:

```
// Load the data from the XML file 
    $.get('data.xml', function (xml) {
        // Split the lines
        var $xml = $(xml);

        // push series
        $xml.find('series').each(function (i, series) {

            var seriesOptions = {
                name: $(series).find('name').text(),
                data: []
            };

            // push data points
            $(series).find('data').each(function (i, value) {
                var seriesData = {
                    x: parseInt($(value).find('axis').text()),
                    low: Date.UTC(parseInt($(value).find('low').text())),
                    high: Date.UTC(parseInt($(value).find('high').text()))
                };
                seriesOptions.data.push(seriesData);
            });

            // add it to the options
            options.series.push(seriesOptions);
        });
```

Remarks:

- if there is a better format than UTC to parse the XML date to please specify
- if there is a better format to store the datetime in the XML please specify
- if there is an JSON easyer alternative to all this please write the equivalent code

(I'm a beginner both in jQuery and XML files, haven't worked with JSON at all)

Comment: Well your parser and soltuion looks like fine, but maybe better is update your back-end to return time in miliseconds instead of format yyyy,mm,dd,hh,mm,ss.

Comment: Well, I found the solution, it was actualy in the XML and a bit in the parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the XML date format,it should be like yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss , not comma separated like I've put them, also this should be parsed in the code like:

```
var seriesData = {
                    x: 0,
                    low: Date.parse($(value).find('low').text()+" UTC"),
                    high: Date.parse($(value).find('high').text()+" UTC")
                 };
```

Comment: With comma you need to split string and push to Date.UTC. Morever " UTC" is nt required in the Date.parse();

Comment: @SebastianBochan if I don't put " UTC" it takes my date and displays it -4 hours.